# MQTT ACK implementation - event listening break

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mqtt

I am having a trouble in implementing the ACK in order to get feedback that a message was delivered using MQTT. My conception lies on providing an id among the message sent by the sender so that the receiver sends back an ACK with the same id on a different channel. Now the issue occurring is that I cannot break the listening on event when I receive the ack.

So far my code is

```
let mqtt = require('async-mqtt')
, cfg = require('./cfg');

let client = mqtt.connect(cfg.server);
client.subscribe('some/other/topic');

client.on('connect', sendWithAck)
let id = 123;

async function sendWithAck() {
  try {
    await client.publish('some/topic', `Message with id${id}`, () => {
      client.on('message', (topic, msg) => {
        console.log(`${topic}> ${msg.toString()}`);
        //this.stopPropagation(); //doesn't work
      })
    });
    await client.end();
    console.log('done');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('error', e);
    process.exit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work, because what would happen if the other end never responds (e.g. has crashed). There is no way to know this at a MQTT protocol level, unlike a synchronous protocol like HTTP.

The right approach is to set up the `on('message')` listener before the call to `subscribe` and to use a state machine to record the id of sent messages and remove them when the response comes in. This way you can set up a timer to allow for time out of responses and deal with them appropriately as well.

Comment: @hardlib I agree with your suggestions, but the first thing I need to manage is to break the event on.('message') and return some value.

Comment: Store the promise in the state machine with the id and use that to return the value.